# Swift 3 Date type not encoding as part of custom class

Tags: ios, swift, nsuserdefaults, nscoding, nskeyedarchiver

I'm having difficulty encoding and decoding a Date type property of a custom Swift class with NSKeyedArchiver. I call the KeyedArchiver with:

```
let savedData = NSKeyedArchiver.archivedData(withRootObject: timers)
    let defaults = UserDefaults.standard
    defaults.set(savedData, forKey: "timers")
```

This is the top half of my class declaration:

```
class TimerModel: NSObject, NSCoding, AVAudioPlayerDelegate {

var name: String
var active: Bool
var paused: Bool
var duration: Int
var remainingWhenPaused: Int?
var timerEndTime: Date?
var timerStartTime: Date?
var audioAlert: AlertNoise
var UUID: String
var colorScheme: BaseColor
var alarmRepetitions: Int
var timerRepetitions: Int
var currentTimerRepetition: Int
var audioPlaying: Bool
var player: AVAudioPlayer = AVAudioPlayer()
var countDownTimer: Timer = Timer()
var delegate: timerProtocol? = nil

init(withName name: String, duration: Int, UUID: String, color: BaseColor, alertNoise: AlertNoise, timerRepetitions: Int, alarmRepetitions: Int, timerEndTime: Date? = nil) {
    self.name = name
    self.active = false
    self.paused = false
    self.duration = duration
    self.UUID = UUID
    self.audioAlert = alertNoise
    self.colorScheme = color
    self.alarmRepetitions = alarmRepetitions
    self.audioPlaying = false
    self.timerRepetitions = timerRepetitions
    self.currentTimerRepetition = 0

    super.init()
}

convenience override init() {
    self.init(withName: "Tap Timer 1", duration: 10, UUID: Foundation.UUID().uuidString, color: .Red, alertNoise: .ChurchBell, timerRepetitions: 1, alarmRepetitions: 0)
}

// MARK: NSCoding

required convenience init? (coder decoder: NSCoder) {

    guard let name = decoder.decodeObject(forKey: "name") as? String
    else {
        print("init coder name guard failed")
        return nil
    }

    let duration = decoder.decodeInteger(forKey: "duration")

    guard let audioAlertRawValue = decoder.decodeObject(forKey: "audioAlert") as? String
    else {
        print("init coder audioAlert guard failed")
        return nil
    }
    guard let UUID = decoder.decodeObject(forKey: "UUID") as? String
    else {
        print("init coder UUID guard failed")
        return nil
    }
    guard let colorSchemeRawValue = decoder.decodeObject(forKey: "colorScheme") as? String
    else {
        print("init coder colorScheme guard failed")
        return nil
    }

    let alarmRepetitions = decoder.decodeInteger(forKey: "alarmRepetitions")

    let timerRepetitions = decoder.decodeInteger(forKey: "timerRepetitions")

    guard let audioAlert = AlertNoise(rawValue: audioAlertRawValue)
        else{
            print("No AlertNoise rawValue case found")
            return nil
    }
    guard let colorScheme = BaseColor(rawValue: colorSchemeRawValue)
        else{
            print("No BaseColor rawValue case found")
            return nil
    }

    var timerEndTimeUnwrapped: Date?

    if let timerEndTime = decoder.decodeObject(forKey: "timerEndTime") as? Date {
        timerEndTimeUnwrapped = timerEndTime
    } else {
        timerEndTimeUnwrapped = nil
    }
    print("initCoder guards passed, initing timer")
    print("\(name), \(duration), \(UUID), \(colorScheme), \(audioAlert), \(timerRepetitions), \(alarmRepetitions), \(timerEndTimeUnwrapped)")

    self.init(withName: name, duration: duration, UUID: UUID, color: colorScheme, alertNoise: audioAlert, timerRepetitions: timerRepetitions, alarmRepetitions: alarmRepetitions, timerEndTime: timerEndTimeUnwrapped)
}

func encode(with aCoder: NSCoder) {

    aCoder.encode(self.name, forKey: "name")
    aCoder.encode(self.duration, forKey: "duration")
    aCoder.encode(self.audioAlert.rawValue, forKey: "audioAlert")
    aCoder.encode(self.UUID, forKey: "UUID")
    aCoder.encode(self.colorScheme.rawValue, forKey: "colorScheme")
    aCoder.encode(self.alarmRepetitions, forKey: "alarmRepetitions")
    aCoder.encode(self.timerRepetitions, forKey: "timerRepetitions")
    aCoder.encode(self.timerEndTime, forKey: "timerEndTime")
}
```

When I try to unarchive the object from NSUserDefaults the `timerEndTimeUnwrapped` always comes back as `nil`. Either I've messed up unwrapping the thing or either the encode or decode are failing. Everything else comes back as expected, it's just the date type that is problematic

Any help would be great.

Comment: Try to convert `Date` to `NSDate`, `aCoder.encode(self.timerEndTime as NSDate, forKey: "timerEndTime")`

Comment: Thanks Nirav D, I found the issue - literally been battling with this for over a day, I'd missed setting the timerEndTime in the init function of the class

Answer (score 1):

So this is a really stupid mistake, problem with adding properties once a class is being used a lot. I wasn't setting the timerEndTime in the `init` function of the class!